# How to round all the values of a prop.table in R in one line?

Tags: r, rounding

In R 3.4.0, how can I round all the percentages generated by prop.table() to 3 decimal places in one line?

This does not work:

```
MyTable$MyCol %>% table() %>% prop.table()*100 %>% round(.,3)

        -7          -2          0          1          2          3         4         5 
 0.4672897  0.2336449 31.7757009  1.6355140 44.3925234 20.3271028  0.4672897  0.7009346
```

expected something like:

```
   -7     -2    0       1      2     3       4      5 
 0.467  0.233 31.775 1.635 44.392 20.327  0.467  0.700
```

Comment: Could you show a small example

Comment: Cols: -7          -2          0          1          2          3         4         5 Values: 0.4672897  0.2336449 31.7757009  1.6355140 44.3925234 20.3271028  0.4672897  0.7009346

Comment: Please update in your post.  I tried with an example, but after the prop.table, I get a rounded number as it is multiplying by 100

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You need to separate multiplication into a separate operation:

```
mtcars$cyl %>% table() %>% prop.table() %>% `*`(100) %>% round(2)
```

Answer (score 4):

We can also use `{}` to evaluate the (`...`) as a whole within the `%>% ... %>%` before switching to the next `%>%`

```
mtcars$cyl %>%
   table() %>%
   prop.table() %>% {. * 100} %>% 
   round(2)
.
#     4     6     8 
# 34.38 21.88 43.75
```

Answer (score 1):

Init data

```
a <- c(0.4, 0.2336449, 31.7757009, 1.6355140, 44.3925234, 20.3271028, 0.4672897, 0.7)
```

First way

```
format(round(a, 3), nsmall = 3)
# [1] " 0.400" " 0.234" "31.776" " 1.636" "44.393" "20.327" " 0.467" " 0.700"
```

Second way

```
options(digits=3)
a
# [1]  0.400  0.234 31.776  1.636 44.393 20.327  0.467  0.700
```

Answer (score 1):

In R 3.5.1 the following works for me:

```
data=sample(1:5, 100, replace=T)

round(prop.table(table(data)),3)

#data
#   1    2    3    4    5 
#0.16 0.24 0.16 0.18 0.26
```

Unless I'm missing something, that seems to give more or less the desired.